# Which time period is deemed appropriate to delete an unanswered question from a network site in order to repost it on another site?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I made the mistake of asking a question on StackOverflow. The problem with it is that questions asked there are likely to end up at the bottom of the stack in no time due to the high number of old questions edited/new questions asked per minute, and it looks like I've even chose the worst time to ask because in less than two minutes the question was in second page already (in the `Newest` section! I couldn't even see it in the `Active` section), and the last time I checked it was already in the oblivion of the tenth page.

Any detail added to bump it up would be just trivial, since the question is clear already.

It's not likely to be seen/picked up at this point, and it got only 3 views within the first minute (probably while it was still in the first page).

Which would be an appropriate time period after which I could delete such question and ask it again on Ask Ubuntu instead? It's about a compilation problem with `make`/`gcc`, so it fits well on Ask Ubuntu as well.

Comment: [so] is waaaaaay bigger than any if the other SE sites. No one's question lasts on the front page. That doesn't mean you won't get an answer. Give it a day or two.

Comment: @Seth I moved it already, got a working answer in less than an hour here :)

Comment: @kos I second Seth - I don't think anyone browses the new questions page unfiltered, they'd go insane. Usage of favourite tags is much higher on [so] than elsewhere.

Comment: @muru In the you're probably right, that's what I do either over there actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no convention for deleting and reposting AFAICT, so whenever you wish. Whether it is on-topic however... Compilation problems are typically on-topic because they come up during software installation from source. On the other hand, if you wrote the program yourself and are looking for debugging help, I'd vote to close it in a flash.